# ubuntu 12.10 web apps does not work

Tags: 12.10

I just updated from 12.04 to 12.10 but I can not find how to add web apps - gmail.
If I opened gmail in chrome and later in firefox nothing happened. 
How to add them? Do I need install something before?

Comment: The same on my fresh Ubuntu 12.10. Ubuntu web apps don't work in chromium: I've tested on gmail, facebook, google plus and youtube. In firefox gmail and omgubuntu work, but there is no additional gmail entry in messaging menu.

Comment: I tried firefox but it does not work also

Comment: @Kamyk I looked in the ubuntu software center but do not see "Unity WebApp extension for the chromium browser" at all.

Comment: this issue may be related to [bug #1059456](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-webapps-googleplus/+bug/1059456), also linked in the [QuantalQuetzal release notes page, under known issues](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QuantalQuetzal/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop#WebApps-1). no workaround is available at the moment.

Comment: see also [bug #1061056](https://bugs.launchpad.net/libunity-webapps/+bug/1061056) on a related issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install 'Unity WebApp extension for the chromium browser' from Ubuntu Software Center. Then restart Chromium and go to gmail website

Write 'chromium webapp' in search box.